# Typescript Class Becoming Empty

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given a specific setup in typescript I end up at runtime with empty class objects in javascript. The setup is simply 2 classes referencing each other will equal one of them being empty in the scope of the other. I know how to avoid it (by introducing a third class in between the 2) but I'm curious as to why it happens and is there a way to still make those cross references and still have a working code. I tried tons of setup to try to make it work so here's what I found.

Setup: each class in its own module (module names and class names irrelevant)
ClassA is our main entry:

// ClassA

```
import ClassB = require('ClassB');
import ClassC = require('ClassC');

class ClassA
{
    constructor()
    {
        console.log(ClassC.TEST);// shows 1
        new ClassB();// shows null
        console.log(ClassC.TEST);// shows 1
    }
}
export = ClassA;
```

// ClassB (in different module)

```
import ClassC = require('ClassC');

class ClassB
{
    public static ClassBRef:any;

    constructor()
    {
        console.log(ClassC.TEST);// in this scope ClassC is an empty object with no properties
    }
}
export = ClassB;
```

// ClassC (in different module)

```
import ClassB = require('ClassB');

class ClassC
{
    public static TEST:number = 1;

    constructor()
    {
        ClassB.ClassBRef;
    }
}
export = ClassC;
```

Because ClassB references ClassC and ClassC references ClassB here's the result: ClassC within ClassA scope exist without problem but within ClassB scope, ClassC is an empty object at runtime with no properties. In other words in typescript everything is fine but javascript will not have it. Changing module names, location, class names, using static or instance scope, in constructor or instance methods or static methods, etc .. makes no difference and ClassC is always empty in ClassB scope.

Like I said the fix is to have a third class handling communication with the 2 faulty classes (so at least one of the 2 classes has NO references to the second one) but again my question is, how to do it without needing a third class and without removing the cross reference between the 2 classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular reference between `ClassB` and `ClassC`.  In any JavaScript environment it's really hard to resolve these problems.

You have two scenarios basically.

`ClassB` is `require`d.
`ClassC` is `require`d.
`ClassC` attempts to `require` `ClassB`.

In this case since ClassB is still being built (it hasn't exported anything) then it will be undefined.  The reverse can happen if `ClassC` is loaded first.

There is a way you can solve it, without extra files however it "feels" wrong.

```
import containerC = require('ClassC');
// or import * as containerC from 'ClassC'; in ES6 syntax

export class ClassB
{
    public static ClassBRef:any;

    constructor()
    {
        console.log(containerC.ClassC.TEST);// in this scope ClassC is an empty object with no properties
    }
}

// ClassC
import containerB = require('ClassB');

export class ClassC
{
    public static TEST:number = 1;

    constructor()
    {
        containerB.ClassB.ClassBRef;
    }
}
```

This is possible because the value returned by require will be populated by the time the `constructor` of either class runs.

You cannot use `export = X` syntax, you must use the named export syntax.  You also cannot try to access either class until after the module loads. So it must be in a constructor or function that is called after the class is exported.

Comment: Thx for the explanation, I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Both posted answers are good but this one has more explanation as to why my setup fails. Accepted. Another question would be why typescript compiler sees no problem with that setup. Also because my typescript project is auto generated (from another language) I will keep the third class bridge solution as it fits best in the converted code. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use the syntax
`import { ClassC } from "./ClassC";` for importing the classes, instead of `import ClassC = require('ClassC');`

Class B:

```
import { ClassC } from "./ClassC"; // use this syntax

class ClassB
{
    public static ClassBRef:any;

    constructor()
    {
        console.log(ClassC.TEST);
    }
}
export { ClassB };
```

Class C:

```
import { ClassB } from "./ClassB"; // use this syntax

class ClassC
{
    public static TEST:number = 1;

    constructor()
    {
        ClassB.ClassBRef;
    }
}

export { ClassC };
```

Comment: I'll try that too and report back.

Comment: notice the syntax to export the module too. It's `export { ClassC }` instead of `export = ClassC` .